# What kind of algebra is this going on?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me? How is this possible and what kind of algebra is this?
$$2^{n+1} = 2^n + 2^n\tag{1}$$
$$2^n  + 2^n = 2 \cdot 2^n\tag{2}$$

Comment: $a^n a^m = a^{n+m}$

Comment: @Ed_4434, According to that logic, 1) should be 2^n+1 = 2^n + 2^1 . Right? But how it is 2^n + 2^n ?

Comment: What on earth do you mean?????  $a + a = 2a$  And $a^na^m  = a^{n+m}$.  So $2^n + 2^n = 2*2^n = 2^{n+1}$. What do you mean "what kind of algebra?"  It's the basic law of exponents.

Comment: Why would $2^{n+1} = 2^n + 2^1$?????  $a^{n+m} = a^{n}a^m$ so $2^{n+1} = 2^n*2^1 = 2^n*2 = 2*2^n$.

Comment: The first admittedly weird looking   identity only work for base $2$. @fleablood 's comment explains why.

Comment: There goes fleablood again with his question mark vomit

Comment: The exponent is for $\times$

Comment: This is true because $2 = 1+1$.  This will not be true for any number where $a \ne 1+1$ but if $a = 1+1$ it has to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm guessing your confusion is about how on earth can $a^{n+1} = a^n + a^n$? Which as you point out doesn't make any sense and isn't usually true.

But.... $a^n + a^n = 2a^n$.  That's clear.

And $a^{n+1} = a*a^n$.  That's clear.  And if $a \ne 2$ then $a^n =2a^n \ne a*a^n = a^{n+1}$.

But if $a$ is EQUAL to $2$ what happens?....Well...

So when we say $2^n + 2^n = 2*2^n$ that is true because $a^n + a^n=(1+1)a^n = 2a^n$.

And when we say $2^{n+1} = 2*2^n$ that is true because $a^{n+1} = a*a^n$.

So in the one and only case where $1 + 1 =a$ that will be the only and only time that $a^n + a^n = 2a^n = a*a^n = a^{n+1}$.  This can *ONLY* happen if $a = 1+1$.